# Streaming live video over private wifi to iPhone for the hearing impaired

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ios

I am researching a project for a theatre company that would like to offer its visitors a live video of sign language, streamed to their smartphones (ex. iPhone in this case) during a show for the hearing impaired.

This is to be only over wifi but must handle multiple iPhone devices being fed.

A modern mac mini, video camera, and wifi router are already available at the server end.

I did find a few options ([1](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Streaming_for_the_iPhone), [2](http://www.jumitech.com/page.php?page=cam), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093667/http-live-streaming-ffmpeg-ffserver-and-iphone-os-3)).

But am curious if anyone has direct experience having done something like this already?

Lastly, the option to develop a custom iPhone app is not out of the scope either.  But I figure such a task has been done many times before and so why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Some form of HTTP streaming would probably be the simplest option, then you only have to get a video streaming web server, no work at all at the iPhone end.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** I like that, VLC was also my first thought.
Add a webserver in the mix and you're done.
This should get you trough the first phases of testing, maybe it's even suitable for production.

**Option 2:** There should be plenty out of the box solutions, this one doesn't look too convincing, but it's a good road to be walking.

**Option 3:** If you're going to get serious about this and make something from scratch yourself, this would be the way to go.
Here's an article I found on the subject: http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/

If you run into network speed problems you might have to look into a broadcast protocol instead of http.

If you can avoid building an app, that would be great. Please look into making this compatible with Android from the start!

Just print a QR code for a URL on the ticket or something, so every breed of smartphone can use this.